# How can you set a Google Apps Script Dialogue Box answer to a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a google apps script that asks for an answer in a pop-up box. I want a variable to be set to the dialogue box answer. I have the code for the asking,  I just need the code for the variable setting.

For example,

```
 // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    Logger.log(MenuOpen());
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('You must input an Address.');
    Logger.log(onOpen());
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You must input an Address.');
    Logger.log(onOpen());
  }
}
```

It will ask for an email address, but I want the answer to be stored in a variable. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad. Please add more details like a [mcve] and a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: "No effort shown --> no answer given" is a good guideline to remember when dealing with volunteer basis readiness such as this website. You have the internet at your disposal - use it. Learn.

Comment: That is a great guideline to follow. Thanks!

Comment: in your example code, you already do this - you have stored the response from the dialog box in the variable `text`. Probably your actual question is along the lines of "how do i perform input validation" and "how do i keep asking until i get valid input" -- both of these are well documented online; you will need to show some research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function findFileInAFolder() {
  var response=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Find File Name in FolderId', 'Enter FolderId/Filename', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(response.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var rA=response.getResponseText().split('/');//Using a delimiter like this allows you to input two variables with just one prompt.
    var files=DriveApp.getFolderById(rA[0]).getFiles();//The First one is a folder Id
    Logger.log(files);
    while(files.hasNext()){
      var file=files.next();
      if(file.getName()==rA[1]) {//The second one is a filename
        var output=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
        var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);//This creates the html for a dialog
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'File Contents');//This creates a dialog to show the file content if is simple text.  If you try to read something like a google doc or a spreadsheet then you will probably get a malformed html error.
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Input Prompt Dialog:

[image]

My Output Prompt: (output will be different for you and your file)

[image]